# How to access data resources files in Python Poetry based projects?

Tags: python, project-structure, python-poetry

Understanding Python Poetry 1

I came across a strange problem.
A small application - dictionary, working in the command line:

```
$ lexi
Usage: lexi word

$ lexi zoo
зоопарк

$ lexi qwerty
There's not word 'qwerty' is in the lexicon
```

The project structure:

```
.
├── poetry_test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── data
│   │   └── lexicon.json        # dictionary file
│   ├── lexi.py
├── pyproject.toml
```

lexi.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
 
import sys
import json
 
LEXICON_DB = "poetry_test/data/lexicon.json"
 
 
def main():
    args = sys.argv
    if len(args) != 2:
        print("Usage: lexi word")
        sys.exit(1)
    
    word = args[1]
    lexicon = json.load(open(LEXICON_DB))
    translation = lexicon.get(word)
    if translation:
        print(translation)
    else:
        print(f"There's not word '{word}' is in the lexicon")
 
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I run in the project root folder with the command

```
$ poetry run lexi zoo
```

it works fine in all ways.

After installing the distribution with the command
`$ python3 -m pip install .` command `lexi` becomes available everywhere in the system, i.e. the installation of the package's been successful:

```
$ lexi
Usage: lexi word

$ whereis lexi
lexi: /home/paalso/.local/bin/lexi
```

In the project root folder `lexi`, already without `poetry run` also works fully OK

But when I try to run it elsewhere in the system with an argument - a word to translate, when the data file lexicon.json is supposed to be accessed, an error occurs:

```
$ lexi zoo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/paalso/.local/bin/lexi", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/paalso/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/poetry_test/lexi.py", line 16, in main
    lexicon = json.load(open(LEXICON_DB))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'poetry_test/data/lexicon.json'
```

That is, the data file data/lexicon.json appears to be unavailable, i.e., during installation, it does not appear to be installed, i.e. it does not get into the system with the application.
How to fix this?
So far I have not found it in the Poetry docs

[git link](https://github.com/paalso/poetry-test/tree/main/poetry_test)

Answer (score 5):

The prefered way to get access to data files of a package is [importlib.resources](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib.resources). There's also a backport called [importlib-resources](https://pypi.org/project/importlib-resources/).

After you've put an `__init__.py` file into the data folder, you can open a file e.g. like this:

```py
lexicon = json.load(importlib.resources.open_text("mypackagename", "data/lexicon.json"))
```

Answer (score 2):

finswimmer's solution doesn't work for me (`python 3.11`).

```py
raise ValueError(f'{path!r} must be only a file name')
ValueError: 'data/lexicon.json' must be only a file name
```

Poetry provides a fairly simple but non-obvious solution:
[pyproject.toml - [poetry.tool]include = [...]](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude)

```py
[tool.poetry]
...
include = ["resource/resource.txt"]
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you add what directory structure you're using here and how you access the resources?

Comment: See my second answer - I can't figure out the formatting for comments.

Comment: Thank you very much! You could have just edited your first answer though! :)

Answer (score 1):

An answer to a question on my other answer (to get formatting).

```
helloworld/  
│  
├── resource/resource.txt  
├── src/helloworld/helloworld.py  
├── LICENSE  
├── README.md  
├── poetry.lock  
└── pyproject.toml
```

Comment: As the `Help` link next to the comment box when entering a comment states, Comments use mini-Markdown formatting, specific details provided at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). Comments are really only for clarifications as the link states, not for answering questions though some people do if the answer is straight-forward. As @necklace states you should have edited your original answer to include this detail. This answer risks being marked as `low quality` or `not an answer` and could be deleted as on it's own it is not complete.